# Pagination in dataprovider is not working properly yii2

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app, yii2-basic-app

I am using a `ActiveDataProvider` in a page and displaying data in a `listview` like below but the problem is that pagination is not working properly. Below is the code for view file and search controller file as well

```
public function search($params)
{
    $query = Mainads::find();

    $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
        'query' => $query,
        'pagination' => [
            'pageSize' => 20,
        ],
        'sort' => [
            'defaultOrder' => [
                'created_date' => SORT_DESC,
                'id' => SORT_DESC,
            ]
        ],
    ]);

    $this->load($params);

    if (!$this->validate()) {
        // uncomment the following line if you do not want to return any records when validation fails
        // $query->where('0=1');
        return $dataProvider;
    }

    $query->joinWith(['adsImages']);

    $query->andFilterWhere([
        'id' => $this->id,
    ]);



    //$to_price = $params->to_price;
    $query->andFilterWhere(['like', 'title', $this->title])
        ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'description', $this->description]) 
        ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'location', $this->description])
        ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'image', $this->image]);


    return $dataProvider;
}
```

Here is my controller action code

```
public function actionIndex()
{
    $searchModel = new UserAdsSearch();
    $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);

    return $this->render('index', [
        'searchModel' => $searchModel,
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    ]);
}
```

And below is the view file code

```
<?= \yii\widgets\ListView::widget([
            'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
            'itemView' => 'listview',
            'layout' => "{pager}\n{items}\n{pager}",
        ]); ?>
```

But it creates pages after 4 items instead of 10 items,is there anything wrong i am doing here??

Comment: Have you rewritten search method or copy/paste? Because it return null.

Comment: @FabrizioCaldarelli i mean i did not include whole code of search method because i thought it wont affect but i am editing the code now

Comment: can you post the controller action that return the dataprovider to the view?.

Comment: @RumesShyaman I have updated the code

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because of your joinWith statement:

```
$query->joinWith(['adsImages']);

$query->andFilterWhere([
    'id' => $this->id,
]);
```

Try the following instead of above:

```
$query->joinWith(['adsImages']); $query->andFilterWhere(['trim(id)' => $this->id,
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any error in this code.find that the view is loading the related dataprovider. any way if the correct data provider is loading then try change page size in controller using lick this.

```
$searchModel = new UserAdsSearch();
$dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);
$dataProvider->pagination->pageSize = 10;
```

may be this will work.